# Why arrays are const in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm working on [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/), and at some point TSLint sugested I re-define an array variable as `const` instead `let` saying:

```
let pages = [];
```

> "Identifier 'pages' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)"

But as arrays are mutable variables, why use a `const` should be prefered than `let`?

Comment: [related](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const).

Comment: `const` means the variable itself is immutable, not the data that the variable is pointing at.

Comment: You can find a lot of information about this by Googling. Long story short, `const` means that you can't reassign the identifier and has nothing to do with value immutability. This is usually a good enough security for programmers, so try to use it as much as possible. 



https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Answer (score 5):

Const has nothing to do with the mutability of the data that the identifier refers to, only whether it is possible to reassign the identifier to something else entirely. In other words, the following is illegal:

```
const foo = [1,2,3]
foo = [4,5,6]
```

Whereas it can be done with let:

```
let foo = [1,2,3]
foo = [4,5,6]
```